Can I have identiers looked up first as members of this, and then as globals?
I write JS (well, EcmaScript), but only relatively rarely.
When writing on a member function for an object, I naturally often use other member variables and functions multiple times; but I tend to avoid defining my own globals, and no less importantly, I make an effort to avoid aliasing globals with members I define.
Given that state of affairs, I'm annoyed by having to use this all the time, e.g.:
this.memberA = this.methodB(someInputArg, this.memberC);

I would really like to just say:
memberA = methodB(someInputArg, memberC);

and have memberA, methodB and memberC be looked up first in the scope of this, then in the global scope.
Can that be done?

Not possible in any useful long-term way. Not really going to be possible ever. foo and this.foo are just different things. Changing the two to be the same has huge impact on all existing code.

Seems like you want with back.

@jonrsharpe it's the not-long term way. Since it has to be repeated every time it needs to be used. Which means that instead of bar(this.foo) you'd need to write with(this) { bar(foo) } which is more verbose and disruptive and less safe than just using this

@jonrsharpe: Seem's like that's what I want. Is it just deprecated, or gone for good?

@VLAZ: Can't I do that at the whole-method level? whole-object level? Whole-file level?

@einpoklum whole method yes - but for each and every method. Whole object - not really. It's chicken and egg problem - how would with (egg) { egg = { /*definition */ } }. Certainly you can't do that with classes - you need to add the this to the scope chain and there is no this outside of methods.

@VLAZ: So, perhaps you can make that into an answer about the use of with, at which scope, the deprecation, etc.?

I could but 1. it doesn't really solve the question. It's a Y workaround of a bandaid to X.2. with is one of the worst features of JS that needs to die. It's deprecated for a reason.

So, what would you say my "X" problem is, if my question is the "Y"?

Y is with, X is your question. And the Y here is very indirect.

The point is that you shouldn't try to bend a language to your esthetics. If it doesn't have a feature, get used to it. JavaScript isn't C++, the designers explicitly chose to require a different syntax for accessing instance variables than normal variables. FYI, the same decision was made for PHP and Python. None of these languages allow you to access instance variables like normal variables (PHP requires $this->variable, Python uses self.variable).

One likely reason for this is that accessing properties of this uses the same syntax as accessing properties of other objects.

@Barmar: DRY? Also... I'm a C++ developer. Bending the language to local aesthetics is a hallowed tradition with that language. We can add syntactic features which language designers have not thought about, e.g. new infix operators, or static blocks etc.

Most programmers considered Bourne to be an eccentric for using a slew of macros to make his C code look like Algol.

That's how it works in C++, Java, ... but the way this gets its value is different in JavaScript, and if methods are called with a different this than you'd expect in Java and C++, then a syntax where you can omit this is going to be very confusing.

@trincot: I don't really see how with(this) do { memberA = methodB(someInputArg memberC); } is confusing.

@einpoklum, Mozilla Contributors write: "Use of the with statement is not recommended, as it may be the source of confusing bugs..."

But I hope you get the point of how this is really a different beast in JavaScript compared to what it represents in C++ and Java. It causes for its own amount of confusion as can be seen in Stack Overflow questions like here, here, ...etc, and syntax that will make this implicit, is going to multiply the cases of confusion (and bugs).

@trincot: I know this behaves differently in JS than in C++ and Java. But I still don't see how collecting the this. prefixes in a with - all within the body of the function - is a problem. Whatever this is when that function is executed - it will be exactly the same when using with.

The MDN article gives examples what could wrong. Imagine a method like go(x) { with (this) { count+=x; } }. Let's assume  obj is an instance of the class and obj.count is 0 and you call obj.go(1), then after the call obj.count will be 1. Now you have code that does obj.x=10000;, and call again obj.go(1). And now obj.count is 10001.  That is not intuitive.

@trincot: It is to me - you always prefer fields of this to anything else. That's what with is all about. And there's a scope change clearly marked by the curly braces. But I suppose bugs could sneak in that way.

There is no sensible, idiomatic, and ergonomical way to do this. Nor is it likely to happen in the future. Any solution would be a huge trade-off in terms of readability, maintainability, and hackyness.
The reason is that when trying to reference an identifier, JavaScript would always use the scope resolution, while referencing an object's property is different to that. Any change to such mechanics would need to go against fundamental design of JS, thus lead to sacrificing features and code clarity for very little (if any) benefit.
It is also unlikely this would ever be revised in JavaScript, as it would still require to deal with legacy code.
The best bet here is to write a plugin for an existing transpiler that changes to check this first then the identifier. So, from
foo(bar)

to
(this["foo"] ?? foo)(this["bar"] ?? bar)

However, I would advise against doing even that. The benefit is too small and the risk too great.
Consider using a proper linter which would tell you if you use an undefined variable (in cases where you missed the this) and configure your editor to show identifiers and properties differently, to make it easy to distinguish at a glance which one of the two you have. If you use any type checking option (like TypeScript or Flow or others), there would also be an error when bar and this.bar (assuming both exist) are of different types but used in the wrong place.

You're using circular logic to justify your claim, i.e. you're saying that locally changing the identifier lookup is bad because it would affect that change. Then you say it's bad because it "sacrifices features and code clarity"; yet - nothing is sacrificed in the language; I would choosing which "features" to use, and the programmer will choose - explicitly - the local form the code should take, to ensure clarity.

@einpoklum you can't use classes if you use with. That's not circular, that's a fact. If you choose to do that, you lose the choice of a language feature. Other approaches put different limits on what constructs and syntax you can use - Alexander Nenashev's answer also forces you into using constructor functions because you can't do the same with classes. Using anything that forces you to write unidiomatic code makes said code harder to understand and maintain. Again, not circular - it's the impact of adopting a construct that ties your hands.

Using this has own benefits in terms of scoping, you can declare any parameters and local variables and they won't clash with this' props. Otherwise you could use so called "hard objects", I was using them for years with success.
Answerting the OP's questions:

Can you elaborate on the difference between the members in the "assign" statement and the other members?
All public members should be assigned to this to be available on the instance.

Can I do something similar without defining a constructor?
No. The pattern is about using only a constructor to build your instance. All variables inside it are private, the public ones are assigned to this. Otherwise there's with statement which isn't recommended.

You can use a mixin pattern to gradually enhance your instances with other instances.




function MyClass(){
  
  Object.assign(this, {publicMethod, publicProp: 'public'});
  
  let memberC = 2, memberA = null;
  
  function methodB(someInputParam, param2){
    return someInputParam + param2;
  }
  
  function publicMethod(){
    memberA = methodB(2, memberC);
    console.log(memberA);
  }
  
}

const my = new MyClass;
my.publicMethod();





Can you elaborate on the difference between the members in the "assign" statement and the other members? 2. Can I do something similar without defining a constructor? i.e. for a plain object I initialize with myobj = {} and gradually add members to with myobj.foo = function() { whatever }?

